# Number of possible sequences from X apples

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Let's say that I have collected 26 apples from the apple tree. 21 of these apples are ripe, whereas 5 of these apples are unripe. How many ways are there of picking 2 ripe and 2 unripe apples if the order does not matter. Then lastly, how many possible sequences of 4 apples can be formed from it?

For the first part:
We know that there are $\binom{21}{2}$ ways of selecting 2 ripe apples and $\binom{5}{2}$ ways of selecting 2 unripe apples. Given that we aim to select 4 apples in a total of 26 we then have $\binom{26}{4}$.

Lastly combining all of these together we get: $$\frac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{21}{2}}{\binom{26}{4}}$$

While I usually know this method by practice, I'm unsure what the actual principle is called that allows me to divide the combinations in the numerator by that value given in the denominator. I'm guessing this is relative frequency?

Furthermore, for the second part.

I know that there are 4! ways of re-arranging the sequences of 4 apples. However, I'm unsure of how to proceed from here and would largely appreciate some support.

Comment: When you are asked questions of "*how many ways*" then you are to answer in whole number quantities, not in probabilities.  The fraction you gave was a probability.

Comment: With regards to your questions... "*I'm unsure what the actual principle is called...*"  I'm not sure what you are expecting as an answer here.  Maybe read about the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) or read about basic definitions of probability.  The point being that each of the $\binom{26}{4}$ ways of choosing four apples (*order unimportant*) are equally likely to occur.  When dealing with an equiprobable sample space $S$ we have $\Pr(A)=\dfrac{|A|}{|S|}$...

Comment: The tag [Self-Learning] is not meant to be used just because you are studying mathematics on your own.  This was a question about something specific in combinatorics and so deserves those tags.  The [Self-Learning] tag is meant for questions like "*If I am teaching myself topology, should I try to give myself tests?  How would I even go about getting those tests graded and what would be considered a good result?*"  Questions about the *action* of learning on your own, not questions about the content of what you are studying.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the tips as I seemed to miss the comprehension of the question. I see well the only other way I can see the calculation working is by removing the denominator and leaving the numerator as is. Given that it represents the number of ways in picking a ripe apple and unripe apple. As for the sequences of apples, do you have any hints?

Comment: Yes.  $\binom{5}{2}\binom{21}{2}$ is the correct answer for the first part.  As for the second part, $\binom{5}{2}\binom{21}{2}\cdot 4!$ is fine, or an alternate way of writing it might have been $\binom{4}{2}\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 21\cdot 20$ would also have been acceptable.  The first having chosen the apples then the spaces... the second having chosen the spaces and then the apples.  Both are of course equal.

Comment: N.B. When moving to probabilities, you should recognize that $\dfrac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{21}{2}}{\binom{26}{4}}=\dfrac{\binom{4}{2}\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 21\cdot 20}{26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23}$, emphasizing that the probability is the same that we draw two unripe apples whether we were to have looked at order as relevant or as irrelevant.  It is our choice whether we describe our sample space as having order relevant or not, and it is usually out of a concern of aesthetics or amount of arithmetic involved that we often prefer order not mattering.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah I see now! I think having the hypergeometric form really put me off on my reasoning. Perhaps it's not always true, but I will at least apply 'sequences' and 'how many' together for now. I enjoy your last comment, as I find that ordering is usually down to arithmetic for my purposes at least. Before I do my reading on the hypergeometric mean, can the binomials be represented as permutations rather than combinations, i.e. in the form $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ in the hypergeometric distribution if order does matter?

Comment: Sure, but notice the $\binom{4}{2}$ term there that appeared describing the number of ways of designating some spots for unripe and leaving remaining spots for ripe.  So long as I avoided making typos... $\dfrac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}} = \dfrac{\frac{K!}{(K-k)!}\frac{(N-K)!}{(N-K-(n-k))!}\binom{n}{k}}{\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}}$.  The one on the left is far easier to write.